# Inserting new entries with Laravels upsert function with no key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to pass an array that has both existing and new rows I would like to insert into my `QueueLane` model by using laravel [upsert](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts) function.

The code:

```
QueueLane::upsert([
    ['name' => 'Existing Lane Update', 'id' => 5],
    ['name' => 'A New Lane', 'id' => null]
], ['id'], ['name']);
```

You can see the first row has an `id`, so I want to update the `name` column with whatever value is in the array, the second row, however, doesn't have an `id` so I want this record to be created.

When running the code I get the following error:

> null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint

I'm expecting the Laravel to populate the ID with a new auto incrementing integer as is the usual behavior for new records in the Model.

Comment: I've never used `upsert` with `id` property. I think it is useful when you need something like "If I have a role with `editor` name, update it or create a new one". When you say "If I have a QueueLane with `null` id" I think it throws an exception. Did you try to not send any id in second one? Because Laravel is not populate next `id`, database does and inform Laravel about it's value.

Comment: I tried to remove the `id` attribute from the second row and the error is still the same.

Comment: Best bet is just setting the `id` to -1 or any unreachable value because the `id` field may not be null, so when Laravel is trying to check for the list of ids, -1 is not found, therefore creating a new row.

Comment: I have tried the `upsert()` and have come to the same problem as the original poster. In Eloquent with auto incrementing tables you do not set the id on the data to save and just let the databse to put the correct id for you. I don't see how @felixbmmm sugestion can help here. Any solution on this?